# KnockoutJs paramatized dependentObservable Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a *viewModel* with an *observableArray* that gets updated from the server, then I need to be able to define a dynamic number of divs to filters of that *observableArray*.

It's a scrum board example, So imagine you receive an array of stories back from the server. and you add the to **viewModel.stories()** observableArray.

I'd like to have template bound filters for various different values of a property of each story within the observable array.

So given

**item.BoardState is "Backlog" or "In Progress"**

I want a dependent observable that I can paramatize to only show stories that are **"In Progress"**

```
    self.filterInProgress = ko.dependentObservable(function (filterParameter) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.stories(), function (item) {
        console.log("Current Filter = " + filterParameter + "--- Current BoardState = " + item.BoardState);
        return ((item.BoardState === filterParameter));
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it says it doesn't work. any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always move the filter out to a separate function and create a dependentObservable for each filterType:

```
function filterStories(stories, filterParameter) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(stories, function (item) {
        console.log("Current Filter = " + filterParameter + "--- Current BoardState = " + item.BoardState);
        return ((item.BoardState === filterParameter));
    });
}

self.filterInProgress = ko.dependentObservale(function() {
    return filterStories(self.stories(), "InProgress");
});

self.filterBacklog = ko.dependentObservale(function() {
    return filterStories(self.stories(), "Backlog");
});
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that bindings are executed in dependentObservables, so if you don't want to create a number of these filtered dependentObserables in your view model, then you can actually just bind it like:  `data-bind="foreach: filteredStories('InProgress')"` and it will update when the observableArray changes (in this case `filteredStories` would be like your `filterStories` but assumes `self.stories()` as the array.  Just another option to keep a balance between bloating the view model and adding too much logic in the template.  Would do a jsFiddle, but seems too slow right now

Comment: Another option is to create a single dependentObservable that is a mapped version of stories.  It would be an object like `{ InProgress: [...], Backlog: [...] }`.  Then, you can bind like `data-bind="foreach: mappedStories().InProgress"` or if you are looping through the choices like `data-bind="foreach: mappedStories()[key]"`.  The advantage to this is that when the array changes there is only one pass through `stories` rather than a pass for each filter.  Probably won't make much difference in a small app though.

Answer (score 0):

Move parameter to View-Model and use custom bindings. So You will have no problem with it.

Look for this example that were born while I discuss this question with my college some time ago.

Demo - http://jsbin.com/epojol/5

Code with preview - http://jsbin.com/epojol/5/edit#javascript,html,live

Custom binding from demo:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.rangeVisible = {
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                var selectedValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                var itemRange = allBindings().range;

                if (selectedValue < itemRange.max && selectedValue >= itemRange.min)
                    $(element).show("slow");
                else
                    $(element).hide("slow");
            }
        };
```

Binding in html:

```
<div class="plan red" data-bind="rangeVisible: selected, range: {min: 0, max:10}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

View:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filterInProgress">
    <h1 data-bind="text: Id"></h1>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {

    stories: ko.observableArray(
        [
            {
                'Id': 0,
                'BoardState': 'In Progress'
            },
            {
                'Id': 1,
                'BoardState': 'Backlog'
            },
            {
                'Id': 2,
                'BoardState': 'In Progress'
            }            
        ]
    )
};

viewModel.filterInProgress = ko.computed(
    function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.stories(), function(item) {
            return item.BoardState == 'In Progress';
        });
    }
)

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

EDIT: now works as an ko.dependentObservable (ko.computed in 2.0)